# Spark 2.1.0 "except" or "intersect" on Canonical case class Fails due to Expression "inputadapter_isNull" is not an rvalue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use except / intersection methods of Dataframe / Dataset, but unfortunately I found that if the dataset or the dataframe holds a canonical case class the operation will fail. I also noticed that both methods contains:

> @note Equality checking is performed directly on the encoded
>   representation of the data    * and thus is not affected by a custom
>   `equals` function defined on `T`

Any suggestion what is the best approach ?

**Example Code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq
case class TestString(str : String)
case class CanonicalExample(tString : TestString)

object GroupOperations {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("GroupOperations").master("local[2]").enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
    import spark.implicits._
    val list1 = List[TestString](new TestString("a"), new TestString("b"), new TestString("c"))
    val list2 = List[TestString](new TestString("d"), new TestString("e"), new TestString("c"))
    val df1: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[TestString](list1)
    val df2: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[TestString](list2)
    //This is working !!!
    df1.except(df2).show()
    val list3: Seq[CanonicalExample] = list1.map(t => new CanonicalExample(t))
    val list4: Seq[CanonicalExample] = list2.map(t => new CanonicalExample(t))
    val df3: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[CanonicalExample](list3)
    val df4: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[CanonicalExample](list4)

    //This Will fail !!
    df3.intersect(df4).show()
  }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
16:55:24 [main] [CodeGenerator.logError]: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 253, Column 34: Expression "inputadapter_isNull" is not an rvalue
/* 001 */ public Object generate(Object[] references) {
/* 002 */   return new GeneratedIterator(references);
/* 003 */ }
/* 004 */
/* 005 */ final class GeneratedIterator extends org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator {
/* 006 */   private Object[] references;
/* 007 */   private scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs;
/* 008 */   private boolean agg_initAgg;
/* 009 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec agg_plan;
/* 010 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap agg_hashMap;
/* 011 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeKVExternalSorter agg_sorter;
/* 012 */   private org.apache.spark.unsafe.KVIterator agg_mapIter;
/* 013 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric agg_peakMemory;
/* 014 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric agg_spillSize;
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in 2.1.1, 2.2.1 and 2.3.0. Have you tried a newer version?

Comment: Amazing!! It is working for 2.1.1. Unfortunately I will not upgrade soon. Thanks !

Comment: What cluster manager do you use? With YARN and Mesos you can use any version, if you don't mind larger jars.

Comment: I am using standalone - and anyway currently I workaround it using map twice with flat model and un flat model later.